# How do I subdivie Ctrl+n an object in Python?

Tags: python, scripting

I have discovered that I can create an object like

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size); 
sphere1 = bpy.context.active_object
```

I also see that Blender logs something like

```
bpy.ops.object.subdivision_set(level)
```

when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in the macro window. But what is the object that the op is applied to? How can I apply it to the `sphere1` in the script?

Comment: What is the 'macro window'? Ctrl+N is the default shortcut for reloading the start-up file.

Answer (score 1):

`subdivion_set`, it seems, is the Subdivison Surface modifier (by default actually is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for me).

Those `bpy.ops.` methods apply to the currently active object. It's good that you created one by `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size)`, because it creates all all necessary things AND selects the created object. There is good page about different methods for creating meshes in the documentation at [3 ways of creating objects](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Three_ways_to_create_objects).

**TLDR**, right after you created object with `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size)`, call `bpy.ops.object.subdivision_set(level)` without any variable setting for sphere.

Comment: That probably answers my question except that the code that I demonstrated in an `mkSphere` func. I do not want all spheres to be highly detalized. This function returns an object that I have a difficulty to subdivide.

Comment: I tried `sphere1.select = True; bpy.context.scene.objects.active = sphere1; O.subdivision(5)`, which succeeds but has not effect